# Swift: use not operator functionally

Tags: swift, functional-programming, not-operator

I would like to get the opposite of a boolean value using dot syntax.

E.g.

```swift
let digitsExceptForFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let fives = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(!digitsExceptForFive.contains)
// Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool'
```

The following code works, however.

```swift
let digitsExceptForFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let notFives = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(digitsExceptForFive.contains)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need to get the opposite value functionally using the not operator. If it's possible I would like not to have to define a bool extension or custom operator just to do so.

How can you do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just extend `Sequence` protocol constraining `Element` to `Equatable` and implement a `notContains` method:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    func notContains(_ element: Element) -> Bool { !contains(element) }
}
```

---

```
let digitsExceptForFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let fives = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(digitsExceptForFive.notContains)  // [5]
```

---

You can also extend `Bool and` provide a `negated` property, this would allow to use negated [`KeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath) syntax:

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
let string = "abc12345" 
let nonDigits = string.filter(\.isWholeNumber.negated) // "abc"
```

---

if you really want to implement a custom prefix operator (I really prefer using the notConstains method and the Bool negated instance property) you can do something like:

```
prefix func !<T>(predicate: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool { { !predicate($0) } }
```

---

Usage:

```
let string = "abc12345"
let nonDigits = string.filter(!\.isWholeNumber) // "abc"

let digitsExceptForFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let fives = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(!digitsExceptForFive.contains) // [5]
```

Comment: In ruby, from what I have read, `notContains` is referred to as `reject`, which in my opinion is clearer. I appreciate each of your suggestions. I am especially impressed with your custom prefix operator.

Comment: As my personal opinion, this is not boilerplate code any developer should need to write in a batteries-included language like Swift, due the diverse potential solution implementations that have been presented and would thereby impair code portability & comprehension.

Comment: @IliasKarim I only use the Bool negated property on my projects. The rest is what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you nonetheless for your contributions, Leo. With support from developers like you `notContains`, `reject` or a custom prefix operator could become a first-class Swift language feature in a further release. I encourage you to particpate in the Swift Evolution disussions should you not already.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to write something like `digitsExceptForFive.contains.not`.

Sadly, you can't, because that would require the type `(Int) -> Bool` to have a `not` method. Functions cannot have methods.

You could write an overload of operator `!` to do it (letting your first attempt work), but I wouldn't recommend it. Operator overloads tend to slow down compile times and confuse later readers of the code.

I recommend you just write it this way:

```swift
let fives = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter { !digitsExceptForFive.contains($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This language support needs to be added to Swift for ergonomic semantics. Please refer to the [evolution pitch discussion on the Swift Evolution forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/toggled-or-isfalse-property-method-on-bool-for-use-with-keypath-apis/51464).